# To change an array such that maximum element in an array must be minimum

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have an array `[4,7,1,3,6,5]`, and I need to transform it such that the maximum element in that transformed array must be minimum.

So for the above example, without changing the total sum value of that array, the array can be transformed into `[4,4,4,4,5,5]` so answer will be 5 (maximum element is minimum).

We can increment or decrement an element of an array by any value without altering the total sum.

For clarity another example:

Given array `[4,1,0]` such that we can modify it as `[2,1,2]` so that maximum element which is minimum is 2.

Comment: Sounds intriguing - can you show some of your code and specify exactly where it goes wrong?

Comment: Are you conducting aptitude exam :)

Comment: Paste your code also what you have tried for this..

Comment: Seems like simple arithmetic to me.

Answer (score 3):

Algorithm:

1: Sum all numbers (26)

2: Divide the sum by the total number of elements (26 / 6) and then round the number to the nearest lower integer (4)

3: start adding this integer to a new array until it is impossible to fill the rest of the array with only fours and then start to add fives (next integer)

```
// Don'f forget #include <cmath> or <math.h>
int arr[], int N;

int answer[N];

int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) sum += arr[i];
int num = floor(sum / (double)N);

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (sum == (N - i) * (num + 1)) answer[i] = num + 1;
    else answer[i] = num;
    sum -= answer[i];
}
```

Comment: for test case [4,1,0] answer must be [2,1,2] but your answer is [1,1,1].

Comment: My answer is [1, 2, 2]
I've forgot to change "nums" with "(N - i)"